# how to get the current date and time of the system in java

Tags: java

I need to get the `current date and time` of the `system` in `Java` and the put a condition that if its `12 PM` then send mail to some people.

Basically a `timer`. So how can I achieve it ? 
I don't want to use `quartz timer` or `crontab expression` but want to to do it in `Java only`.

Please explain with the help of an example.

Comment: Just what have you tried?

Comment: `new Date()` for example or `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: try with java.util.Date

Comment: I have to time the function actually after getting the date and time.. @RC.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis`?

Comment: `TimerTask` can help you

Comment: my favourite date time class is Joda Time, http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get date with time

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

And the code

```
       Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
       SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY-hh:mm:ss");
       String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
       System.out.println(dateNow);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
Date date=new Date();
if(date.getHours()==12){
    //send mail
}
```

For more on `Date` visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) link.

Comment: @suganya you should accept the correct answer.

Comment: @Kumar yeah but it allows to accept the correct answer after 10 mins...:)

Comment: That's ok. please ignore the comment. @suganya

Answer (score 1):

[`#getHour`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29) method is deprecated so don't use it,you can use [`#SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead.

```
    Date date=new Date();//Current date
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
    //H will give hour 0 to 23 
    if("12".equals(dateFormat.format(date))){
        System.out.println("It's 12 PM");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how to check the current time/date.....

just take a look at java.util.date
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

It has everyrhing about finding the date

and as for the time, a simple if/else statement will do...
I'm assuming you know how to send mail

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Joda LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) library.

Like:

```
new LocalTime().isEquals(new LocalTime(12, 0, 0))
```

You can read about the [LocalTime(int, int, int)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#LocalTime%28int,%20int,%20int%29) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a");
Date date = new Date();
String time=dateFormat.format(date);
```

using this you can get the current system time and date and after that you just check the time and send mail