# How can I specify the date format in Java?

Tags: java, date

I am working on a Java application and I have the following problem trying to format a date.

So I inizialize an object field with a new **java.util.Date;** that represent the current date time, this one:

```
progetto.setDatOraUltMov(new Date());
```

When I print this field the result is somethind like this:

```
Mon Oct 12 17:19:06 CEST 2015
```

Ok, this standard is not good for my pourpose and I want that is shown something like this:

```
12/10/2015 17:19:06
```

Something like in the format **DAY/MONTH/YEAR HOUR:MINUTE:SECOND**

How can I do something like this? How can I specify the required date format?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602291/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-of-the-system-in-java/26602398#26602398

Comment: Did you google? [format java date](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=format+java+date)

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
```

For your reference

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: incorrect, need `DAY/MONTH/YEAR HOUR:MINUTE:SECOND`

Comment: Have you tried "dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss", have you even looked into the simpledate format reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
       Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
       SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY-hh:mm:ss");
       String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
       System.out.println(dateNow);
```

import

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
```